# ISO-Image Format is used instead of others?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, iso-image, zip

I have seen almost all operating systems and large sized files are in ISO format. why they choosen that format instead using any other formats like zip, rar, etc.

Comment: ISO is direct copy (byte-by-byte) which do not need decompression or another transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary large files, in general, *could* be distributed as .zip archives (any format would do, but Zip has the most support across systems). There is a big difference when you're distributing **operating system installation** files, however.

The formats you have listed are not *disk image* formats: they only contain files but none of the sur­round­ing filesystem structure, e.g. no boot sector, no partition types. They can be understood by pro­grams on the already-running OS, but not by the firmware to start an OS *from*.

To create a bootable disk, you would have to convert the .zip archive into some other format that's recognizable by the computer's firmware – e.g. BIOS-bootable disks must have a boot sector, or a partition table with specific partition types for UEFI, or an ISO9660 filesystem for CDs/DVDs.

- If you were using UEFI, it *might* be enough to simply reformat the disk using FAT32, and extract the files from a .zip archive onto that disk. But the user would have to be careful to pick the correct filesystem type, to not accidentally move or delete some files, and so on.
- And that's not enough for BIOS systems, and not quite that easy for bootable CDs either – you would need to distribute at least two files; the contents themselves plus the boot sector; and trust the user to correctly write both.

So instead of making every user do this work separately (possibly with differing results), the OS distributors do the conversion *themselves*, and provide the *final* image for download, ready to be written 1:1 to a disk.

(The files are called ".ISO" because they originally contained a 1:1 image of a compact disc, in the [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) format. The naming convention continues even for UDF or hybrid CD/HDD images.)